# Find all changes in filesystem done by a process in Linux/Mac?

Tags: linux, security, command-line, process, lsof

Let's say I am going to run a Mac program that will be doing some patching in my home directory. The program requires ROOT privileges to run and I don't know for sure what it does indeed because I don't have source code.

## How can I see a list of all changes in file system by a program?

I know I can list currently opened files by `lsof -p pid` . But how do I see retrospectively all changes that the program made in my entire file system?

Another thing that comes to mind is using `find` but I didn't figure that one out.

Side question. Does the `pid` change when the app gains ROOT privileges?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strace` to record all actions done by application.
In fact it can trace all children which could be spawned by original command.

```sh
strace -o traces -ff ./your-app-to-trace
```

this will generate multiple trace files (one file per process).
Then you can grep them to see what files were touched and what was written to them.

Comment: this is good! Although I need to find some working equivalent for MacOs